# React Native - React Navigation rerender panel on goBack()

Tags: react-native, refresh, react-navigation, rerender

I am using [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) in my app. How can I refresh the data on my previous panel when going back to it?

A practical example would be:
I am currently in **Panel A**, I navigate to **Panel B** where I update data in my database which is displayed in **Panel A**. After I *goBack()* to **Panel A** after changing the data in the database I wish **Panel A** has now rerendered and holds the new data from the database.

I have read that I can pass a custom refresh function as params to the child class and call it before navigating back, however I think this is not a neat way to achieve what I want since I update a component which is not yet mounted and I can just throw an error.

Comment: Are you using redux? what do you mean by database? Local state or redux or API called data?

Answer (score 6):

This is how i achieved!

**In Panel A**

```
refreshFunction()
{
    //your refresh code should be here
}

 <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{
   this.props.navigation.navigate('PanelB', {refreshFunction: this.refreshFunction});
 }}>
    Redirect to Panel B
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

**In Panel B**

```
const refreshFunction = this.props.navigation.state.params.refreshFunction;
if(typeof refreshFunction === 'function')
{
  refreshFunction();                
  //your back function
  this.goBack();
}
```

Comment: Related solutions in issue: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/922

Comment: React navigation added one more approach (i guess createStackNavigator) which unmount the compoenent in redirect action. So each time render component will trigger componentDidMount method.

Answer (score 2):

[React Navigation provides listeners](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle) which can be used for this exact scenario.

For example, attach a listener to **Panel A**, which will re-fetch the updated data when focused (i.e. when **Panel A** is "popped back" to):

```js
componentDidMount() {
  const { fetchDatabaseData, navigation } = this.props
  fetchDatabaseData()
  this.willFocusListener = navigation.addListener(
    'willFocus',
    () => {
      fetchDatabaseData()
    }
  )
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.willFocusListener.remove()
}
```

Comment: And with Navigation version 5 I used 'focus' instead of 'willFocus'. This worked.

Answer (score 1):

After so much searching, conclusion: yes you can:

```js
render(){
...
   <NavigationEvents
      onWillFocus={() => {
      //Call whatever logic or dispatch redux actions and update the screen!
      }}
   />
...
}
```

Source: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1171

Answer (score 0):

Using redux + firebase I had the problem where the observable data from `firebase.on('value', snapshot => { dispatch(data) }` that was `mappedToProps` would update the redux store on save, before the component that listed that data returned to view `onBack()`, so no re-render would trigger in the list. I solved it by comparing past to current props and re-triggering the firebase.on fn only when the props did not match. This is better than always firing when the list component is navigated to, but I'd prefer a solution that forcefully triggers a re-render without calling the firebase fn at all.

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.data !== this.props.data) this.props.fetchdata();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per navigation [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/) for navigation events

```
function Profile({ navigation }) {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      // do something
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);

  return <ProfileContent />;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

If you have may scenarios, like this, you can use **redux**, which help you to manage data across tabs/screen and in the component because reduces is connected to store, in the redux store entire application state is managed.

Comment: Using redux is not a solution to the problem asked.